# spring boot + junit + overriden component instance

Tags: java, junit, spring-boot

I've got sample project [here](https://github.com/bilak/axonframework-poc). I'd like to setup som junit test with class `com.github.bilak.axonframework.poc.command.user.UserTest`
When I run test, I can see in log

> Skipping bean definition for [BeanMethod:name=userCommandHandler,declaringClass=com.github.bilak.axonframework.poc.command.config.CommandConfiguration]: a definition for bean 'userCommandHandler' already exists. This top-level bean definition is considered as an override.

And then I can see that when UserRepository is injected to UserCommandHandler that's another instance as that which is used in UserTest class. Why this is done and how can I avoid this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because a bean of name *userCommandHandler* is defined twice in context. First as an annotated component `com.github.bilak.axonframework.poc.command.user.UserCommandHandler` registered with component scan, second as a bean defined in *CommandConfiguration* (line 75).

> And then I can see that when UserRepository is injected to UserCommandHandler that's another instance as that which is used in UserTest class.

Looking at the *GivenWhenThenTestFixture* implementation I can see that it actually wraps the passed instance into some adapter. Moreover, because what you passes is actually a spring proxy which has the userRepository direct reference null (that's correct I believe), the effective registered handler has it also null, so you are probably experiencing null pointer exception because of that. If I change the setUp for your test:

```
@Before
public void setup() throws Exception {
    fixture = Fixtures.newGivenWhenThenFixture(User.class);
    UserCommandHandler target = (UserCommandHandler) ((Advised) userCommandHandler).getTargetSource().getTarget();
    fixture.registerAnnotatedCommandHandler(target);
}
```

It helps.

Comment: ok this works for me...but when I rename userCommandHandler in CommandConfiguration shouldn't it work?

Comment: sure, only you'd need to use qualifiers to decide which one to inject to your test then. This only solves the _Skipping bean definition_ warning however, the proxy thing is separate issue.